# How to disabled js function?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a bootstrap tab menu and I made my tab responsive on tablet and mobile devices if you check out my demo on mobile or tablet - when you resize the page less than 768 px you will see my responsive tab. but if I resize my page again to >768px I want to get my tabs menu again as non responsive (default) and I guess I have to kill my function ? how can I do that ?

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/LLKQyM)

```js
!function(t){var o=function(){var o,e=[],n=!1,i=function(t){clearTimeout(o),o=setTimeout(d,100)},d=function(){for(var t=0,o=e.length;t<o;t++)e[t].apply()};return{register:function(o){e.push(o),!1===n&&(t(window).bind("resize",i),n=!0)},unregister:function(t){for(var o=0,n=e.length;o<n;o++)if(e[o]==t){delete e[o];break}}}}(),e=function(e,n){this.element=t(e),this.dropdown=t('<li class="dropdown hide pull-right tabdrop"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">'+n.text+' <b class="caret"></b></a><ul class="dropdown-menu"></ul></li>').prependTo(this.element),this.element.parent().is(".tabs-below")&&this.dropdown.addClass("dropup"),o.register(t.proxy(this.layout,this)),this.layout()};e.prototype={constructor:e,layout:function(){var o=[];this.dropdown.removeClass("hide"),this.element.append(this.dropdown.find("li")).find(">li").not(".tabdrop").each(function(){this.offsetTop>0&&o.push(this)}),o.length>0?(o=t(o),this.dropdown.find("ul").empty().append(o),1==this.dropdown.find(".active").length?this.dropdown.addClass("active"):this.dropdown.removeClass("active")):this.dropdown.addClass("hide")}},t.fn.tabdrop=function(o){return this.each(function(){var n=t(this),i=n.data("tabdrop"),d="object"==typeof o&&o;i||n.data("tabdrop",i=new e(this,t.extend({},t.fn.tabdrop.defaults,d))),"string"==typeof o&&i[o]()})},t.fn.tabdrop.defaults={text:'<i class="icon-align-justify"></i>'},t.fn.tabdrop.Constructor=e}(window.jQuery);

function tabMobile() {
  if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    $(' .nav-tabs').tabdrop({
      text: 'Click to navigation',
      align: 'right',
    });
  } else {
    //kill function here
  }
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  tabMobile();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  tabMobile();
});
```

```css
.main {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<div class="main">

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Configuration</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
  </div>

</div>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: 'kill' a function? Do you mean like making a bool and guarding the call against that?

Comment: Why not use media queries (or even take advantage of Bootstrap's grid system) to get things where you want them?

Comment: I want to make my tab responsive on tablet and I'm using plugin. if my resulution is less than 768px than make my tab responsive but if is not don't make my tab responsive, you can see my demo if you click to demo link and if you resize the page for mobile you will see it will be responsive but if my resulution is not less than 768 px I don't want to make it responsive

Comment: I suggest you should use media queries instead of JS to vary your layout according to screen size

Comment: I guess you don't understand my question I'm using jquery plugin to use responsive and I have to with jquery

Comment: We might not understand because you are not telling us what you want the result to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up some things here...

First of all, tabdrop will automatically display only if needed. So using your bootstrap should be enough to make it collapse on smaller screens.

Second thought, you might want to use bootstraps nav-bar example, it is a good start point to having a responsive menu.

Third, as a bonus: making something responsive is not something that acts for mobile (when available screen width is low). Something responsive is something that adapts to the screen size, and responds to changes automatically. You can't make your menu responsive only for < 768, making anything react to a specific resolution would be responsive... Well, trying to sum up real fast.

Comment: so I have tab menu not nav menu I only want to responsive my tab menu and I found a jquery plugin so my condition is for just only 768px as you see and my resulution is bigger than 768 px than call this function is that possible with css media queries ??????? no.

Comment: It is... You could have 2 different menues, one for bigger screens and one for smaller screens. Just use the bootstrap helper classes to make only one show at a time. That's what I'd do.

Comment: there is no two different screen it is a jquery plugin and it is manipulate to html ok thanks.

Comment: I know it is a plugin, I am using it... And it works flawlessly for me. When there is room for the tabs, they show and when there is none the menu shows... You have no reason to call the plugin more than once.

Comment: but it is hiding all li this is not good option..in this(http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-tabdrop/) demo it is hiding only not fit